# Is Device and Partition Association fixed during device registeration by IOT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have 10 devices registered in IoT hub with a basic set of 4 partitions. I am assuming these 10 devices will be associated to 4 partitions internally by IoT hub, please confirm ?

And when these devices send messages on IoT Hub , messages will be enqueued in respective device partition, is my understaning correct?

My point is that any time in future if I read messages so I will always get the same partition for the same device.

Is there any possibility that I am getting messages from same devices from different partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Hub contains many core components from the Azure Event hub which also includes the Partitions and its Partitioning concept.

The routing of the device to cloud message/events to its relevant partition depends on the partition key that you have specified for the device, it can be either Device Group / Location (maybe country based on GDPR compliance), etc.

Having said that for a single partition key you cannot receive the data in different partitions.
For more details, please refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#mapping-of-events-to-partitions

Comment: I am using B1 - Basic plan with 4 partitions. I am adding devices on IOT hub azure portal, no partition selection option is there. Later I am using device connection string to send messages from a client. Another componenet (default group used) consume these device messages as mentioned above. So partition is set automatically by Azure IOT Hub, my question is, once a device registred. would it be associated with a Partition and always remains there until changed explicitely, can my consumer component assume that all messages from a device will be from same partition?